# how to validate empty screenshot in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Is there any possibility to check empty or blank screen shots. Sometimes, the screen shot is blank when am using        TakesScreenshot ss = (TakesScreenshot)driver;

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check

```
public static boolean isFullWhite(Image img) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int w = img.getWidth(null);
    int h = img.getHeight(null);
    int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
    PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
    pg.grabPixels();
    boolean isWhite = true;
    for (int pixel : pixels) {
        Color color = new Color(pixel);
        if (color.getRGB() != Color.WHITE.getRGB()) {
            isWhite = falsee;
            break;
        }
    }
  
   return isWhite;
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31228650

Comment: This is a technically correct but a really bad solution, some hints to why are in the linked answer. You can't practically process full images using for loops, so they suggest to scale it down but this may generate false positives (white image detected although it is not). If you need to verify many images this will grind your machine to a halt. Ideally the correct solution should involve a graphics card operation that can process full images in parallel.